# bash convert text block (multilines) to single line

Tags: bash

After a long search i can not find a solution. Could someone help with this, thx.

start pattern [some digits], end pattern next [some digits].

input:

```
[2450]
some text
keyword1=abc
some text
some text
keyword2=def

[112]
some text
keyword1=abc
keyword2=def
some text
some text

[223]
some text
keyword1=abc
some text
keyword2=def
some text
```

output:

first column: digits between brackets

second column: text from keyword1

third column: text from keyword2

```
2450;abc;def
112;abc;def
223;abc;def
```

Comment: I was posting an answer, then you changed the question...

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F[ '{ if ($0 ~ /\[[[:digit:]]+\]/) { split($2,arry,"]");numba=arry[1] } else if ($0 ~ /keyword/) { bit=split($0,key,"=");dat[numba]=dat[numba]key[2]";" } } END { for(i in dat) { print i";"dat[i] } }' filename
```

With awk, split the lines using "[" as the field delimiter. If the line pattern matches to [number] then extract the number only with split and use this number as the index of an array (dat) Each line is then added to the array dat and this is finally looped through and printed prefixed with the index. The only issue with this solution is ordering. I'm not sure if this is important or not.

Comment: The question has changed.  He also wants to extract key/value pairs now.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. this should be the final output now

Comment: I've changed accordingly

Answer (score 0):

**Input**

```
$ cat file
[2450]
some text
keyword1=abc
some text
some text
keyword2=def

[112]
some text
keyword1=abc
keyword2=def
some text
some text

[223]
some text
keyword1=abc
some text
keyword2=def
some text
```

Output

```
$ awk -F= -v OFS=';' 'function p(){ if(n && k)print n,k; n=k="" }/^\[/{gsub(/[^0-9]+/,""); n=$0}/keyword/{k=(k ? k OFS:"")$2}!NF{p()}END{p()}' file
2450;abc;def
112;abc;def
223;abc;def
```

Better Readable version

```
awk -F= -v OFS=';' '
      function p(){ 
          if(n && k) 
              print n,k; 
              n=k="" 
      }
      /^\[/{
               gsub(/[^0-9]+/,""); 
               n=$0
      }
      /keyword/{
               k=(k ? k OFS:"")$2
      }
      !NF{
              p()
       }
       END{
               p()
       }
       ' file
```

Comment: thanks a lot. how can change this if i want to extract other words too, for example: accountcode=sometext and callerid=sometext

Comment: @calabash like keyword you create `/callerid/{  cid=(cid ? cid OFS:"")$2   }` and then in `function p()` print and reset variable

Comment: the callerid field looks like: callerid=Test User <326>. How can i extract only the name?

Comment: @calabash : `/callerid/{ gsub(/<.*>/,"",$2); cid=(cid ? cid OFS:"")$2 }`

Comment: i have another keyword ;name=sometext. i tried       /^;name\=/{
        n=(n ? n OFS:"")$2
    } but this does not work. how do fix that?

Comment: you are overwriting variable n, use some other variable, read second comment

Comment: gsub(/[^0-9]+/,""); also looks in section that contains letters like [test-test-01]. can you only limit it to numbers. thanks in advance

Comment: `gsub(/[^0-9]+/,"")` will remove anything other than number

Comment: yes it does. but it should only look in the text block which starts with: [only numbers]

Comment: if so please change `/^\[/{` to `/^\[[0-9]+\]/{` so that it will look for line with has just numbers inside brackets

Comment: Can you pls rewrite the code since i have a new requirement.
For example:
[112]
some text
keyword1=abc

keyword2=def
some text
some text

[223]
some text
keyword1=abc
some text

keyword2=def
some text
I want to extract "keyword2". But if an empty line is in the block the keyword2 can not be extracted.

Comment: Can someone help me with the code from @Akshay. If the block contains a empty line i can not extract e.g. keyword2. keyword1 works because it is located before the empty line.

[112]
some text
keyword1=abc

keyword2=def
some text
some text

[223]

Answer (score 0):

you could use:

```
cat test.txt | head -c -1 | sed '/^\s*$/d' | tr '\n' ';' | sed 's/\;\[/\n\[/g' >> test2.txt
```

in this example the command read the file text.txt delete the last byte, replace all empty lines, replace all line breaks with: ";" and replace all occurrences of: ";[" with a newline and: "[". Finally the result is written in the test2.txt file.